# Why is image view stretching to fill half the width in a UIStackView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uilabel, uistackview

I am taking an `UIImageView` on the left of the horizontal stack view and a label with number of lines set to 0. The issue is that both the `UIImageView` and the label are filling equal space even though I have set the stack view distribution property to fill. I don't want my image view to expand. Changing content hugging isn't helping.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is: When telling the stack view to fill the content area it try to do it as best as possible. When setting the distribution type to `fill` it do not know how to fill. You have to provide this information by setting a width constraint via autolayout for the image. The label will fill the remaining area then.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this would be to add an invisible spacer object at the right side of the image + label stack.

```
private func spacer() -> UIView {
    let stretchingView = UIView()
    stretchingView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
    stretchingView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    stretchingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return stretchingView
}

private func labelWithImage() -> UIView {
    let image = UIImage(systemName: "map")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "3 Miles Away"
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .regular)
    label.textColor = UIColor.gray
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [imageView, label, spacer()])
    stackView.alignment = .leading
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    return stackView
}
```

[image: example image]